# useSelector is not updating the state in with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am trying to reset the value of state.portfolio.piechart to an empty object {} but it does not work.

```
const initialPortfolioState = {
  pieChart : {},
  analyzeObject: {},
  constructStartDate : null,
}

const portfolioSlice = createSlice({
  name: "portfolio",
  initialState: initialPorfolioState,
  reducers: {
    resetPieChartAndAnalyzeState: (state) => {     
      state.pieChart = {}
      state.analyzeObject = {}
      state.constructStartDate = null
      console.log('finished setting')
      console.log('the pie chart state is', state.pieChart)
    },
....
  }
});
    },

export const {resetPieChartAndAnalyzeState, ....} = portfolioSlice.actions
```

The state.Piecharts gets updated elsewhere

```
import {resetPieChartAndAnalyzeState} from './portfolioSlice'

const Filters = () => {
  const { pieCharts, toAnalyze } = useSelector(portfolioSlice)

console.log('pieChart') // returns the current value of the pieChart which is an object with data
{.....}

    const openPortfolioFromHeader: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement> =() => {
        // console.log('this should set the piechart to be an empty object')
        dispatch(resetPieChartAndAnalyzeState()); 
        console.log('pieCharts should be empty ')

    }

console.log(pieCharts) // it returns a non-empty object why??
  return (
   <>...</>
  )
```

The pieChart should be an empty object after openPortfolioFromHeader is called, but the state returns the previous value which is a non-empty object

Comment: Are you doing `dispatch(portfolioSlice.actions.resetPieChartAndAnalyzeState())` ?

Comment: Yes I am doing that

Comment: If your code structure is REALLY like that (so the second console.log is on the same level as the MouseEventHandler) this CANNOT work, since the dispatch is generally asynchronous. Try to setup a useEffect with `[pieCharts]` as a dependency

Comment: @devnull69 I want to call the openPortfolioFromHeader in an Onclick so I can't use a useEffect

Comment: No ... the useEffect is NOT for the onclick handler, but rather for the console.log to check the new value of the state whenever it changed

Comment: @devnull69 yes it does eventually get set to an empty object

Comment: so this answers your question, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by creating a copy of the state and then modifying the copy.

```
const portfolioSlice = createSlice({
  name: "portfolio",
  initialState: initialPortfolioState,
  reducers: {
    resetPieChartAndAnalyzeState: (state) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        pieChart: {},
        analyzeObject: {},
        constructStartDate: null,
      };
    },
    // other reducers...
  },
});

export const { resetPieChartAndAnalyzeState, ... } = portfolioSlice.actions;
```

when using useSelector, make sure you are selecting the correct slice of the state:

```
const { pieChart, analyzeObject, constructStartDate } = useSelector(
  (state) => state.portfolio
);
```

Comment: I tried this but still the same result